# jQuery plugin for creating scrolling content

Tags: jquery

I need any `jQuery` plugin that create scrolling content (left to right or right to left).

I fount this one:

http://smoothdivscroll.com/

but it need a lot of addons plugin (like: jQuery ui, jQuery mouse wheel, jQuery kinetic). Is there any plugin that can do it alone, with just `jQuery` and no other plugins?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Google Horizontal Scrolling jQuery and you will end up with lots of results that satisfy your needs.

[Here is a link](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-horizonal-scroll-demos-plugins/) that might interest you.